# find_elements by CSS_Selector Python Selenum

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I realized Selenium removed some attributes, my code is not able to use each_item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR statement:

```
for i in range(pagenum):
     driver.get(f"https://www.adiglobaldistribution.us/search?attributes=dd1a8f50-5ac8-ec11-a837-000d3a006ffb&page={i}&criteria=Tp-link")
     time.sleep(5)
     wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
     search_items = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[class='rd-thumb-details-price']")

     for each_item in search_items:
          item_title = each_item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[class='rd-item-name-desc']").text
          item_name = each_item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[class='item-num-mfg']").text[7:]
          item_link = each_item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='item-thumb'] a").get_attribute('href')
          item_price = each_item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='rd-item-price rd-item-price--list']").text[2:].replace("\n",".")
          item_stock = each_item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='rd-item-price']").text[19:]
    
          table = {"title": item_title, "name": item_name, "Price": item_price, "Stock": item_stock, "link": item_link}
          data_adi.append(table)
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: you are wrong, Selenium did not remove "find_element" but you are getting NoSuchElementException that means the element with that CSS selector was not found in your response

Comment: One of the items in the `search_items` loop doesn't have a price - selenium fails to find the element and raises an exception. When parsing with Selenium like this you should handle all `find_element` for failure as sometimes some details might not be there. Like wrap it in try/catch.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably approaching the whole situation the wrong way. Those products are being hydrated in page by javascript, once page loads, so you can actually scrape the api endpoint and avoid the complexities (and slowness) of selenium. here is a solution based on requests and pandas, scraping the API endpoint (found under Dev tools - Network tab):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }

full_df = pd.DataFrame()
for x in range(1, 4):
    r = requests.get(f'https://www.adiglobaldistribution.us/api/v2/adiglobalproducts/?applyPersonalization=true&boostIds=&categoryId=16231864-9ed5-4536-a8b3-ae870078e9f7&expand=pricing,brand&getAllAttributeFacets=false&hasMarketingTileContent=false&includeAttributes=IncludeOnProduct&includeSuggestions=false&makeBrandUrls=false&page={x}&pageSize=36&previouslyPurchasedProducts=false&query=&searchWithin=&sort=Bestseller', headers=headers)
    df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['products'])
    full_df = pd.concat([full_df, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
# print([x for x in full_df.columns])
print(full_df[['basicListPrice', 'modelNumber', 'name', 'properties.countrY_OF_ORIGIN', 'productDetailUrl', 'properties.minimuM_QTY', 'properties.onsalenow']])
```

Result printed in terminal:

```
basicListPrice  modelNumber name    properties.countrY_OF_ORIGIN    productDetailUrl    properties.minimuM_QTY  properties.onsalenow
0   51.99   TL-SG1005P  TP-Link TL-SG1005P 5-Port Gigabit Desktop Switch with 4-Port PoE    China   /Catalog/shop-brands/tp-link/FP-TLSG1005P   1   0
1   81.99   C7  TP-Link ARCHER C7 AC1750 Wireless Dual Band Gigabit Router  China   /Catalog/shop-brands/tp-link/FP-ARCHERC7    1   0
2   18.99   TL-POE150S  TP-Link TL-POE150S PoE Injector, IEEE 802.3af Compliant China   /Catalog/shop-brands/tp-link/FP-TLPOE150S   1   0
3   19.99   TL-WR841N   TP-Link TL-WR841N 300Mbps Wireless N Router China   /Catalog/shop-brands/tp-link/FP-TLWR841N    1   0
4   43.99   TL-PA4010 KIT   TP-Link TL-PA4010KIT AV600 600Mbps Powerline Starter Kit    China   /Catalog/shop-brands/tp-link/FP-TLPA4010K   1   0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
85  76.99   TL-SL1311MP TP-Link TL-SL1311MP 8-Port 10/100mbps + 3-Port Gigabit Desktop Switch With 8-Port PoE+      /Catalog/shop-brands/tp-link/FP-TSL1311MP   1   0
86  35.99   C20 TP-Link ARCHER C20 IEEE 802.11ac Ethernet Wireless Router   China   /Catalog/shop-brands/tp-link/FP-ARCHERC20   1   0
87  29.99   TL-WR802N   TP-Link TL-WR802N 300Mbps Wireless N Nano Router, Pocket Size   China   /Catalog/shop-brands/tp-link/FP-TLWR802N    1   0
88  100.99  EAP610  TP-Link EAP610_V2 AX1800 CEILING MOUNT WI-FI 6" China   /Catalog/shop-brands/tp-link/FP-EAP610V2    1   0
89  130.99  EAP650  TP-Link EAP650 AX3000 Ceiling Mount Wi-Fi 6 Access Point    China   /Catalog/shop-brands/tp-link/FP-EAP650  1   0
90 rows × 7 columns
```

You can further inspect that json response, andd see if there is more useful information you need from there.
Relevand pandas docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

And for requests docs, see https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/